# Multiple cronjobs in a single crontab

Tags: unix, cron

How do I cd into a directory and run a script in the same crontab? Currently I'm trying to do something like `32 11 19 1 * cd /Users/myusername/Documents && simple.py` but when this runs I receive the error:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=myusername>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=myusername>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/myusername>
Date: Mon, 19 Jan 2015 11:32:00 -0500 (EST)

/bin/sh: simple.py: command not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: why don't you just `/bin/sh /Users/.../simple.py` instead of `cd`ing?

Comment: @fedorqui because I also need to run source bin/activate from Documents.

Comment: the thing is that you miss the `/bin/sh` when calling `simple.py`, so you can also use: `cd /.../... && /bin/sh simple.py`

Comment: @fedorqui hm I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: The environment in crontab is quite small, so it may not know how to run your script. Check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info "Making assumptions about the environment" for further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must precede with `./` when executing the script from the current working directory.

```
32 11 19 1 * cd /Users/myusername/Documents && ./simple.py
```

I guess you script is a python script. `/bin/sh:` seems weird. If your script is a python script then add following line `#!/usr/bin/env python` if it does not already contain it.